# Installation error of GAMS API for Python

Tags: python, api, gams-math

In order to use GAMS from Python, I installed GAMS 24.8.5 x32 and Python 3.6.5 x32.

I followed the instruction for intalling GAMS API for Python  [from GAMS web page](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/API_PY_TUTORIAL.html)

```
C:\GAMS\apifiles\Python\api_36>python setup.py install && cd ..
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
copying build\lib\cfgmcc.py -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages
copying build\lib\dctmcc.py -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages
creating C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gams
copying build\lib\gams\database.pyd -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gams
copying build\lib\gams\execution.pyd -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gams
copying build\lib\gams\options.pyd -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gams
copying build\lib\gams\workspace.pyd -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gams
copying build\lib\gams\__init__.py -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gams
copying build\lib\gamsxcc.py -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages
copying build\lib\gdxcc.py -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages
copying build\lib\gevmcc.py -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages
copying build\lib\gmdcc.py -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages
copying build\lib\gmomcc.py -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages
copying build\lib\optcc.py -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages
byte-compiling C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\cfgmcc.py to cfgmcc.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\dctmcc.py to dctmcc.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gams\__init__.py to __init__.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gamsxcc.py to gamsxcc.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gdxcc.py to gdxcc.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gevmcc.py to gevmcc.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gmdcc.py to gmdcc.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gmomcc.py to gmomcc.cpython-36.pyc
byte-compiling C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\optcc.py to optcc.cpython-36.pyc
running install_data
copying _gdxcc.pyd -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages
running install_egg_info
Writing C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gdxcc-7-py3.6.egg-info
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_data
copying _gamsxcc.pyd -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages
running install_egg_info
Writing C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gamsxcc-1-py3.6.egg-info
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_data
copying _dctmcc.pyd -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages
running install_egg_info
Writing C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\dctmcc-1-py3.6.egg-info
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_data
copying _gevmcc.pyd -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages
running install_egg_info
Writing C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gevmcc-6-py3.6.egg-info
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_data
copying _gmomcc.pyd -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages
running install_egg_info
Writing C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gmomcc-15-py3.6.egg-info
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_data
copying _cfgmcc.pyd -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages
running install_egg_info
Writing C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\cfgmcc-1-py3.6.egg-info
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_data
copying _gmdcc.pyd -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages
running install_egg_info
Writing C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\gmdcc-2-py3.6.egg-info
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_data
copying _optcc.pyd -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages
running install_egg_info
Writing C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\optcc-2-py3.6.egg-info
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Writing C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\GAMS-1.0-py3.6.egg-info
```

The installation seems to be ok, but when I tried to check it by running some examples, every time I got the same error with a DLL

```
C:\GAMS\apifiles\Python>python transport1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transport1.py", line 10, in <module>
    from gams import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\gams\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .workspace import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 no es una aplicación Win32 válida.
```

"No es una aplicación Win32 válida" means "is not a valid win32 valid application"

I had several versions of Python some of them for x64. I uninstalled everything and installed only one x32 version but the same error keeps apearing.

Comment: I believe GAMS comes with its own Python installation, already setup with the API. This might be the most convenient to use, especially together with the embedded python code feature.

Is there a particular reason you do not want to use x64 GAMS? I had little trouble getting that to work, and have not tried x32.

Comment: I develop using x32 because is the system they have where the program is going to run in the end, is not up to me...
Regarding the installation of python, there is none included with gams as far as I know.

Comment: It looks like python is only included in versions 24.9 and later. I don't know what your specific issue is, but often "Program Files (x86)" is a bad place to install things due to having spacing in the path name (and requiring admin rights access), despite being the Windows default.